# Perl: Read binary file and send via socket

Tags: perl, sockets

I am trying to send binary file via UDP socket in Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use IO::Socket;
my $sock = IO::Socket::INET->new(
    Proto    => 'udp',
    PeerPort => 666,
    PeerAddr => '127.0.0.1',
) or die "Could not create socket: $!\n";

my $input;
open $input, "result1.bin" or die "Unable to oen: $!";
binmode $input;
my $data;
my $nbytes;
while($nbytes = read $input, $data, 32) {
        print "$nbytes bytes read\n";
}
my $res = $sock->send($data);
print $res . "\n";
```

My output:

```
32 bytes read

32 bytes read

16 bytes read

0
```

Why the send call doesn't send bytes?

Comment: Have you printed out `$data` inside and after your loop to check what was read?

Comment: @ago, yes. I have printed $data after loop via print hexdump({"data" => $data});
The result was: _Data::Hexdumper: data length isn't an integer multiple of lines
so has been padded with NULLs at the end.
  0x0000 : 48 41 53 48 28 30 78 31 35 37 63 34 34 30 29 00 : HASH(0x157c440)_

Comment: If i change $data to "something string or number" it works. Very strange.

Comment: There's a problem with the call to `hexdump`. `hexdump` expects a hash, but you're passing a hashref. As a result, the output is the dump of the stringified hashref (i.e. `HASH(0x157c440)`). Try calling it as `hexdump(data => $data)`.

Comment: Using UDP for this is very very wrong. UDP doesn't report lost packets, and doesn't guarantee that data will be received in the same order as it was sent. You'd have to use some protocol over UDP that would add that functionality. TCP, on the other hand, does all that natively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies in this line:

```
while($nbytes = read $input, $data, 32) {
```

Since you don't specify an [offset](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/read.html), the `read` function stores the input data at the start of `$data` in each iteration, overwriting the earlier data. In the last iteration when there's no data to be read, an empty string is stored in `$data` and the while loop exits.

Since the size of `$data` is 0, the `send` function does not send anything.

Here's how you can fix the call to `read`:

```
while($nbytes = read $input, $data, 32, length $data) {
```

*Update*: As mentioned in the comments, UDP is not the right approach and the above code may not work you expect since packets may be out of order or even lost.